# Existence of a mapping in a nonseparable Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Do there exist a nonseparable Banach space $X$, a mapping $F: X\to X$, and an open nonempty subset $D\subset X$ such that
$$
\forall\,E>0 \quad \exists\,\delta>0: \quad \forall\,x,y\in D \quad (0<\|x-y\|<\delta \Rightarrow \|F(x)-F(y)\|>E) \, ?
$$

Of course, it is impossible if $X$ is separable.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you assume the mapping $F$ to be linear, continuous or have some other properties?

Comment: No, $F$ cannot be continuous, of course. $F$ is nonlinear, in common.

Comment: Why are you interested in having such a map?

Comment: No. You cannot even make it from $\mathbb R$ to $X$. Indeed, for every $E>0$ any sufficiently short interval has to contain at most one point $x$ with $\|F(x)\|<E$, so the set of points on the line with $\|F(x)\|<E$ is countable, i.e., the line is countable...